# I am using MEN stack(mongo, express,node)

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, web-deployment

I'm working on a project wherein I am using a news api to show the contents of a specified user typed topic,for eg `"technology"` , but the problem is sometimes i get thousands of results and all are displayed on a single page,but i want the `number of pages` of the search result to change dynamically with the typed topic,

for example `tech` may have `100` pages while `sports` may have `500` pages.

How do i do this for my website?

Any sources,links,source code might help me a lot.

Thanks.

Comment: It would help if you showed your code and clarified exactly what functionality you're trying to achieve versus what you're currently observing. Stack Overflow isn't a personal search engine

Answer (score 1):

Use Aggregate paginate module (https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongoose-aggregate-paginate) for pagination and it will take page number and limit as an input and will provide you with that limit of results.

It will also help you to store how many pages are there with the limit decided.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should look into 'pagination'. Basically, you set a number of items per page to return, divide the total number based on the items set per page, and pass in the starting and last index for fetching the data (like the first 2 parameters in a Array.slice method).